# How to reliably init C# static members in PCL from other Assemblies?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I'm working on a collection of code where there's most of the functionality in a PCL. I want to init members like

```
class CentralInPCL {
  public static Func<string> DefaultPathProvider;
```

This needs to be assigned a lambda `() => Path.GetTempFileName()` from an assembly built for **one of the platforms**.

How do I reliably assign this lambda in another assembly?

Can I guarantee a static constructor of a helper class, in another assembly, will be run before any instances of CentralInPCL might be used?

I may have completely mis-understood something about how a PCL works but we're trying to avoid having user code have to pass parameters to the PCL.

As I understand them, a PCL is a *leaf library* called by platform-specific assemblies.

You would normally give it access to platform stuff by *injecting* an object or lambda, typically confirming to an interface defined in the PCL.

However, that injection process is explicit and has to be out there in some platform-specific code, usually user code.

I'm trying to add a bit more magic and have some defaults injected without the user knowing.

Comment: A static constructor in CentralInPC is guaranteed to be called before any instances are created or any static method is called in CentralInPC. But not in another class if that is what you mean.

Comment: The problem I have is that I need the code to be run in a non-PCL context as it's invoking platform-specific libraries.

Comment: If you want this to be deterministic, why not explicitly set them, with some kind of `Initialize()` static method to inject the platform specific bits?

Comment: In addition, your "magic" would be in user land *already*, so it's not clear what your benefit would be?

Comment: We build platform-specific assemblies. Ideally one of them runs the injection method. That's us doing it automatically in userland, but not the user having to write code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An old [2005 answer from Jon Skeet](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/247972-how-force-execution-static-constructor) suggests you couldn't do it, at least back then.

I found a recipe for doing it with Fody, [weaving in a Module Initializer](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/) which is an IL thing not able to be declared in C#.

Failing which, we need to require the user to include a call to setup static defaults somewhere.